# Getting only pages from one liferay server to another

Tags: portlet, liferay-6

I have my liferay server installed on local machine.

I have created pages and an organization.

I want to have the same structure on another machine. H

What all files do i need to copy from this folder to another machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the SQL export and the data folder from liferay-portal. Replace this data folder on the other machine and point it to the DB.  SQL files will have the organizations and the pages while data folder will have the documents, images  and other contents required to initiate the liferay portal.